How to get kubernetes pod labels using fluent-bit LUA filter
I want to enrich my kubernetes events collected through fluent-bit kubernetes_events input. I'm using fluent-bit LUA filter for this use case and I have try two lua scripts, but neither of them worked for me.

using kubectl in lua script

            local involvedObjectKind = record["involvedObject"]["kind"]
            local involvedObjectName = record["involvedObject"]["name"]
            local involvedObjectNamespace = record["involvedObject"]["namespace"]

            if involvedObjectKind == "Pod" then
                local command = "kubectl get pod " .. involvedObjectName .. " -n " .. involvedObjectNamespace .. " -o json"
                print("Executing command: " .. command)

                local handle = io.popen(command)
                if handle then
                    local result = handle:read("*a")
                    handle:close()

                    local json = require('json')
                    local pod = json.decode(result)

                    if pod then
                        print("Pod found: " .. pod)
                    end
                else
                    print("Failed to execute command: " .. command)
                end
            end
            return 1, timestamp, record

This always prints Failed to execute command.

using http calls in lua script

            local involvedObjectKind = record["involvedObject"]["kind"]
            local involvedObjectName = record["involvedObject"]["name"]
            local involvedObjectNamespace = record["involvedObject"]["namespace"]
            local http = require("socket.http")
            local ltn12 = require("ltn12")
            local cjson = require("cjson")

            if involvedObjectKind == "Pod" then
                -- http request to k8s API server to get pod labels
                local url = "https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/" .. involvedObjectNamespace .. "/pods/" .. involvedObjectName

                local response_body = {}
                local res, code, response_headers, status = http.request {
                    url = url,
                    method = "GET",
                    headers = {
                        ["Authorization"] ="Bearer " .. os.getenv("K8S_TOKEN"),
                        ["Accept"] = "application/json",
                    },
                    sink = ltn12.sink.table(response_body),
                    create = function()
                        local sock = require("socket").tcp()
                        sock:connect("kubernetes.default.svc", 443)
                        return sock
                    end
                }

                if code == 200 then
                    local pod = cjson.decode(table.concat(response_body))
                    for k, v in pairs(pod["metadata"]["labels"]) do
                        record["labels." .. k] = v
                    end
                else
                    record["error"] = "Failed to get pod labels"
                end
            end
            return 1, timestamp, record

This fails with the error [error] [filter:lua:lua.1] error code 2: /fluent-bit/scripts/k8s_events_enrichment.lua:5: module 'socket.http' not found:
I want my event to be populated with pod labels and other metadata related to pods. What am I missing here? How to get this resolved?
